# UITableView can not reload data or set value to cell when scrolling or touching?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, reloaddata

For now I connect tableview with my socket connection (real time data ), Tableview will reload data every time that received new data ( about every 2 seconds ).

It working normally, but when I touch tableview or scroll, TableView will not update or reload data anymore

I try to use dispatch async but It not working anymore.Can someone help me ?
Thank you so much.

Comment: Reloading the table every 2 seconds is not a good way. if you get any new data just insert a new row.

Comment: Oh, I have to. It's a socket connection ( about stock ) it is change some value ex. price.

Comment: is your socket received only updated data for one cell? or for all cells at a time?

Comment: all cells at the time.

Comment: If your data has some form of unique identifier you should look at using diffable table view data source.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thank you for ur reply, My application have to support ios12. Diffable datasource is available on ios13+

Comment: how about silent push notification to trigger the table view update?

Comment: If you really must support iOS 12 (approximately 0.8% of iOS installed base, 6+ year old devices) then you will need to do the hard work to identify the changes in the dataset yourself. Reloading the whole tableview every 2 seconds is not going to give a very smooth experience.